# VideoView doesn't play youtube video

Tags: java, android

I am unable to play a youtube video.
I'm trying to play a video in a `VideoView`, but it shows black screen.

I'm using this code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle testVideo) {
    super.onCreate(testVideo);
    setContentView(R.layout.media_player);
    VideoView videoWatch = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setEnabled(true);
    mediaController.show(0);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoWatch);
    videoWatch.setMediaController(mediaController);
    Uri videoLink = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTXCgR93zC8");
    videoWatch.setVideoURI(videoLink);
    videoWatch.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you posted returns an HTML page, and the VideoView is only meant to load image sequences.
Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

Comment: Why My webView can't play on full screen mode. Please Help. Thanks